# Add images to a highchart bar graph

Tags: highcharts

I have a relatively simple (highcharts) barchart and I'm wondering if it's possible to add a small image at the end of each bar (currently where the number is). It needs to be a different image for each bar.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Some Chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Archimedes','Curie','Darwin','Hawking','Newton','Pasteur'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Score',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' percent'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },       
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Group Team Performance',
        data: [
            {name: 'Archimedes', color: '#fe3932', y: 70},
            {name: 'Curie', color: '#28d44e', y:66},
            {name: 'Darwin', color: '#fce621',y:46},
            {name: 'Hawking', color: '#003969', y:66},
            {name: 'Newton', color: '#00afd5', y:64},
            {name: 'Pasteur', color: '#b14fe0', y:56}
        ]
       }
     ]
});
```

});

I've created a quick fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vou3uyyf/1/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vou3uyyf/2/ ? Simply use `dataLabels.formatter` with option `useHTML` set to true. Only limitation is exporting server, which doesn't support HTML tags.

Comment: @PawełFus that wouldn't allow me to set a different image per bar would it?

Comment: Of course it allows you to do that. Just make this URL as param from the point, see: http://jsfiddle.net/vou3uyyf/3/